# QDialog widget with null parent always visible

Tags: c++, qt

I am working with qt 3.3. I need to make QDialog widget with null parent always visible not stays on top (WStyle_StaysOnTop) because this flag block access for main application. I need on screen keyboard functionality for my QDialog widget.

Comment: what do you mean by 'always visible not stays on top'?

Comment: That means always stays on top but allow to access the main application.

Comment: have you tried both `Qt::WStyle_StaysOnTop` and `Qt::WX11BypassWM`? check: http://doc.trolltech.com/3.3/qt.html#WidgetFlags-enum

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I had tried both flag together but still i did't get access to my main application, thats block the access.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I correctly understood the question. Here is a minimal example of what u want.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
```

{

ui->setupUi(this);

```
QDialog *dia = new QDialog(this);
//Set the windowflags
dia->setWindowFlags(dia->windowFlags() | Qt::Tool);

dia->show();

QWidget *central = new QWidget;
QHBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
QLineEdit *edit = new QLineEdit;

//Add sample QLineEdit to test the input focus for mainwindow
mainLayout->addWidget(edit);
central->setLayout(mainLayout);
setCentralWidget(central);
```

}

**edit:**

If you want to be able to minimize and maximize the dialog in question from systray you  have to create the QSystrayIcon and context menu for it:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
```

{
    ui->setupUi(this);

```
QDialog *dia = new QDialog(this);

dia->setWindowFlags(dia->windowFlags() | Qt::Tool);

dia->show();

QWidget *central = new QWidget;
QHBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
QLineEdit *edit = new QLineEdit;
mainLayout->addWidget(edit);
central->setLayout(mainLayout);
setCentralWidget(central);

//Create the icon for systray
//NOTE this icon is application wide 
QSystemTrayIcon *icon = new QSystemTrayIcon(QIcon(QPixmap("/usr/share/icons/oxygen/22x22/status/user-away.png")), dia);

icon->setVisible(true);

//Create context menu to manipulate the dialog
QMenu *contextMenu = new QMenu;

QAction *minimizeDialog = contextMenu->addAction("Minimize dialog");
QAction *restoreDialog = contextMenu->addAction("Restore dialog");

connect(minimizeDialog, SIGNAL(triggered()), dia, SLOT(hide()));
connect(restoreDialog, SIGNAL(triggered()), dia, SLOT(show()));

//Add it to the icon
icon->setContextMenu(contextMenu);
```

}

Comment: You can switch input focus but your dialog will be always on top

Comment: Great..! Thanks Neox for helpful suggestion. As per your suggestion QDialog remains on top and i can also access my main application, But I have also need to minimize that QDialog widget to system tray.

Comment: Thanks for your great work but i am using qt 3.3 and QSystemTrayIcon doesn't available in that.

Comment: Well if you definitely need system tray, than upgrade to 4.8